# SQL Server 2016 - TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xffffffff, status code 0x80

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

After a windows server restart SQL instance does not start with following errors:

```
2021-11-19 05:43:39.72 spid10s Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2021-11-19 05:43:39.72 spid10s TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xffffffff, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support.
2021-11-19 05:43:39.72 spid10s Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2021-11-19 05:43:39.72 spid10s TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0xffffffff, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors.
2021-11-19 05:43:39.73 spid10s Error: 17826, Severity: 18, State: 3.
2021-11-19 05:43:39.73 spid10s Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
2021-11-19 05:43:39.73 spid10s Error: 17120, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2021-11-19 05:43:39.73 spid10s SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems.
```

We had this issue before that instance didn't start automatically after restart but every time we were able to manually start it.
Currently the only option when it starts is when we disable TCP/IP protocols.

Instance is part of Always On Availability Group configuration.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does this [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/fails-start-error-17182) help?

Comment: And from here -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/service-cannot-start -- status code 0x80 indicates that a problem is in the SSL certificate. Two similar problems I've encountered include invisible characters in the certificate value in the registry (covered in the link provided by J.D.) and if the SQL Engine service account doesn't have read-access to the certificate's private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved by changing service account to local system, starting the instance (which was successfull), stopping the instance and changing service account back to the domain one.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Changing service user account or messing with certs, disabling TLS, etc. all had no effect. Turns out the server could no longer see the Domain Controller/Active Directory (searching for users/computers in AD always returned no results, domain user's names wouldn't resolve, etc.) Once the network stack was reset then communication with the domain was restored and the SQL Server service started correctly.
One thing worth noting, I found if you disabled the TCP/IP protocol under the SQL Server Network Configuration in SQL Server Configuration manager, the service would start. This limits you to named pipes, but SSMS works, if you wanted to take a backup, etc.